# Controlling canvas object with range slider

Tags: javascript, canvas, slider

Attempting to place a circular object on a canvas, and alter the position of the object dependent on range slider inputs (x, y).  Currently the object is not placed on canvas, rather than the var cx/cy being a number value they are being returned as [object HTMLInputElement].

Why?

JS code:

```
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth=6;
    ctx.strokeStyle='green';

    var PI2=Math.PI*2; //place the circle on canvas
    var cx = document.getElementById('xpos');
    var cy = document.getElementById('ypos');

    cx.addEventListener('change', drawX, true);
    cy.addEventListener('change', drawY, true);

    var radius=3;
    drawX(0);
    drawY(0);

    var $xpos=$('#xpos');
    $xpos.on('change',function(){
        drawX(parseInt($xpos.val()));
        console.log("hori: " +xpos);
        x = cx;
    });

    var $ypos=$('#ypos');
    $ypos.on('change',function(){
        drawY(parseInt($ypos.val()));
        console.log("vert: " +ypos);
        y = cy;
    });

    function drawX(x){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,cy,radius,0,PI2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        console.log("X range, X axis: " + cx);
        console.log("X range, Y axis: " + cy);
    }

    function drawY(y){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,y,radius,0,PI2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        console.log("Y range, X axis: " + cx);
        console.log("Y range, Y axis: " + cy);
    }

});
```

HTML inputs

```
 <label>X-pos<input type=range id=xpos min=0  value=150 max=300 step=1></label><br>
    <label>Y-pos<input type=range id=ypos min=0 value=150 max=300 step=1></label><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error about the [object HTMLInputElement] is that you try to write the variable `cx` or `cy` while they're both DOM objects (your sliders). If you want to write the values they represent, you should ask for `cx.value` and `cy.value` respectivelly.

Furthermore, you seem to have created eventlisteners twice, one "normal" and one using jQuery.

I remember this code from a previous question of yours and working on the comment from markE, try combining the two draw functions to one and use the values from the sliders. The code will be more compact and nicer, see below.

Also you can remove the `$(function(){` at the top and `});`at the end to make it non-jQuery if you'd wish that.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth=6;
ctx.strokeStyle='green';

var PI2=Math.PI*2; //place the circle on canvas
var cx = document.getElementById('xpos');
var cy = document.getElementById('ypos');

cx.addEventListener('change', draw, true);
cy.addEventListener('change', draw, true);

var radius=3;
draw();

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx.value,cy.value,radius,0,PI2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  console.log("X range, X axis: " + cx.value);
  console.log("X range, Y axis: " + cy.value);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label>X-pos<input type=range id=xpos min=0  value=150 max=300 step=1></label><br>
    <label>Y-pos<input type=range id=ypos min=0 value=150 max=300 step=1></label><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I can see now that I have conflicting pieces of code, and stripping them away created the functionality required

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Just for fun, I stipped the eventlisteners and added a continous loop of painting the dot drawing the values from the sliders. That way the dot will move instantly while the slider is being moved, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/dLfcfh1v/